# Slicing of Python Array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array which I used np. loadtext on an csv file.

```
dataresale = np.loadtxt(
    resale, skiprows=1, usecols=(0,2,10),
    dtype=[('month', 'U50'),
           ('flat_type', 'U50'),
           ('resale_price', 'f8')], delimiter=',')

print(dataresale['month'])
```

Below is the output:

```
['2017-01' '2017-01' '2017-01' ... '2021-03' '2021-10' '2021-12']
```

I would like to only take out data from year 2021 (all months) only

Below is a script I used to take out rows by year in the another array, but this particular dataset has the months tagged to it

```
x = datap[datax['year'] == 2019]
```

Is there a way I can modify the script above to take out all 2021 data?

Comment: Have you tried something like `dataresale[dataresale['month'][:4]=="2021"]`?

Comment: Are they in string format? Or datetime?

Comment: @Grismar i tried it and gave me IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 115402 but corresponding boolean dimension is 4

Comment: @LarrytheLlama the it is in str format

Comment: You probably just shouldn't use `numpy` here, working with strings is going to be unwieldy. In any case, you **really** should provide example data.

Comment: Since I don't have the data on hand, and you didn't provide a representative sample, I can't try myself - but you might have better luck with `dataresale[dataresale['month'].startswith('2021')]`

Answer (score 4):

Construct a sample array:

```
In [359]: arr = np.zeros(6, dtype=[('month', 'U50'),
     ...:            ('flat_type', 'U50'),
     ...:            ('resale_price', 'f8')])
In [360]: arr['month']=['2017-01', '2017-01', '2017-01','2021-03', '2021-10', '2
     ...: 021-12']
```

### startswith

Since the interest is in the first for characters we can do:

```
In [362]: np.char.startswith(arr['month'],'2021')
Out[362]: array([False, False, False,  True,  True,  True])
```

which effectively is:

```
In [364]: [s.startswith('2021') for s in arr['month']]
Out[364]: [False, False, False, True, True, True]
```

The list comprehension is faster, though for better comparison lets get the indices:

```
In [366]: timeit np.nonzero([s.startswith('2021') for s in arr['month']])
15.1 µs ± 23.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [367]: timeit  np.nonzero(np.char.startswith(arr['month'],'2021'))
16.7 µs ± 457 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

### astype truncation

But `astype` is a relatively quick way of truncating string dtypes, effectively the `[:4]` type of string slice:

```
In [371]: arr['month'].astype('U4')
Out[371]: array(['2017', '2017', '2017', '2021', '2021', '2021'], dtype='<U4')
In [372]: arr['month'].astype('U4')=='2021'
Out[372]: array([False, False, False,  True,  True,  True])

In [374]: timeit np.nonzero(arr['month'].astype('U4')=='2021')
6.47 µs ± 7.53 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

### datetime[Y]

another option is to convert the string to `datetime64`

```
In [376]: arr['month'].astype('datetime64[Y]')
Out[376]: 
array(['2017', '2017', '2017', '2021', '2021', '2021'],
      dtype='datetime64[Y]')
```

With the conversion time:

```
In [379]: timeit np.nonzero(arr['month'].astype('datetime64[Y]')==np.array('2021
     ...: ','datetime64[Y]'))
17.5 µs ± 48.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

And if we can justify doing the conversion ahead of time:

```
In [380]: %%timeit yrs = arr['month'].astype('datetime64[Y]')
     ...: np.nonzero(yrs==np.array('2021','datetime64[Y]'))
6.2 µs ± 9.11 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

### char_slice

```
In [396]: char_slice(arr['month'],0,4)
Out[396]: array(['2017', '2017', '2017', '2021', '2021', '2021'], dtype='<U4')
In [397]: char_slice(arr['month'],0,4)=='2021'
Out[397]: array([False, False, False,  True,  True,  True])
In [398]: timeit np.nonzero(char_slice(arr['month'],0,4)=='2021')

37.2 µs ± 101 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: This has really been bugging me, so I opened up [issue #20705](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/20705) with a proposed workaround in [PR 20694](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/20694). There's no reason you shouldn't be able to stride-trick something like this away instead of having to use slow vectorized functions.

Comment: FYI, starting with np version 1.23.0, you will be able to slice this problem away. My PR was merged in, and now I'm working on adding `np.char.slice_`. This was too much of a struggle before.

Answer (score 2):

So, in general, `numpy.ndarray` objects have [limited support](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.char.html) for string operations. Notably, string slicing seems to be absent. If you look at similar questions, you can hack a slice from the front at least using a view (with a small `N` for the `UN` type).  However, since your array is a structured dtype, it doesn't like creating views.

In this particular case, though, you can use the `np.char.startswith` function.

Some example data (please always provide this in the future, you are coming here asking for help, don't make people work to make your own question easy to answer, it's actually part of the rules, but it is also just common courtesy):

```
(py39) Juans-MBP:workspace juan$ cat resale.csv
2017-01,foo,4560.0
2019-01,bar,3432.34
2017-01,baz,34199.5
2019-01,baz,3232.34
2017-01,bar,932.34
```

Ok, so using that above:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: resale = "resale.csv"

In [3]: data = np.loadtxt(resale,dtype=[('month','U50'),('flat_type','U50'),
   ...:                                       ('resale_price','f8')],delimiter=',')

In [4]: data
Out[4]:
array([('2017-01', 'foo',  4560.  ), ('2019-01', 'bar',  3432.34),
       ('2017-01', 'baz', 34199.5 ), ('2019-01', 'baz',  3232.34),
       ('2017-01', 'bar',   932.34)],
      dtype=[('month', '<U50'), ('flat_type', '<U50'), ('resale_price', '<f8')])

In [5]: np.char.startswith(data['month'], "2019")
Out[5]: array([False,  True, False,  True, False])

In [6]: data[np.char.startswith(data['month'], "2019")]
Out[6]:
array([('2019-01', 'bar', 3432.34), ('2019-01', 'baz', 3232.34)],
      dtype=[('month', '<U50'), ('flat_type', '<U50'), ('resale_price', '<f8')])
```

Alternatively, though, in this case you are working with dates, which is a supported type in `numpy`, so you can use the following dtype: `'datetime64[D]'` which will be a datetime64 but parsed by filling in the days for you:

```
In [14]: data = np.loadtxt(resale,dtype=[('month','datetime64[D]'),('flat_type','U50'),
    ...:                                       ('resale_price','f8')],delimiter=',')

In [8]: data
Out[8]:
array([('2017-01-01', 'foo',  4560.  ), ('2019-01-01', 'bar',  3432.34),
       ('2017-01-01', 'baz', 34199.5 ), ('2019-01-01', 'baz',  3232.34),
       ('2017-01-01', 'bar',   932.34)],
      dtype=[('month', '<M8[D]'), ('flat_type', '<U50'), ('resale_price', '<f8')])
```

Then you can use something like:

```
In [9]: data['month'] >= np.datetime64("2019")
Out[9]: array([False,  True, False,  True, False])
```

Comment: The datetime idea is probably the way to go, but isn't there stuff in `np.char`  basically python string operations with a slightly faster version of `vectorize`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist sure, the first part used `np.char.startswith`

Comment: I was asking because you can do slicing just fine here. The only catch is that you have to make a copy of the part of the string you care about.

Comment: @MadPhysicist AKAIK you cant really slice.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, my experience is that the `np.char` functions apply string methods to `numpy` arrays at list-comprehension speeds.

Comment: My answer shows you can. You just have to change the view before and after.

Comment: @hpaulj. I saw your answer related to this. Do you know why contiguity is required in the row dimension? Seems like unnecessary overkill that actually causes harm in this case. I can always bypass it by making a raw `np.ndarray` with blackjack and my own strides, but that seems like overkill too.

Comment: @hpaulj I had heard that they improved this in recent releases, I'm not sure though.

Comment: @hpaulj. I've written a small function that is pretty numpy-compatible which does string slicing in my answer. Might try to get it included in numpy.

Comment: @hpaulj. Sorry to keep bugging you about this. How familiar are you with numpy internals? I've opened up a PR here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/20722 which may fix this issue. Is that something you can meaningfully comment on? If it works out, I'd like to add a more general solution, like the one I started here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/20694, but based on a modified version of `as_strided` that lets me adjust offsets and dtypes too.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. Are the PRs above something you can comment on?

Comment: #20722 got accepted, so I posted another answer. Starting with 1.23.0, you will be able to make views of non-contiguous arrays, and possibly have `np.char.slice_` available. This issue bugged me way more than it should, so I'm fixing it :)

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using numpy, you can extract the data you want to integer format using slicing:

```
strs = dayaresale['month'].copy()[:, None].view('U1')
year = strs[:, :4].view('U4').astype(int).ravel()
month = strs[:, 5:7].view('U2').astype(int).ravel()
```

The conversion to 2D followed by the ravel at the end allows the `'S1'` view to expand into columns. The copy is necessary because the data is not completely contiguous (though it is in the column dimension).

Any mask you construct from these arrays will be applicable to the original, e.g.:

```
dataresale[year == 2021]
```

**PS**

The copy is really bothering me, since the original data is clearly "contiguous enough" to avoid it. If the elements of the string were not in a contiguous block, it would be understandable. I therefore propose the following alternative for string slicing, which is actually a lot cheaper and simpler in some ways:

```
yoffset = dataresale.dtype.fields['month'][1]
year = np.ndarray(buffer=dataresale, shape=dataresale.shape, offset=yoffset, strides=dataresale.strides, dtype='U4').astype(int)
moffset = dataresale.dtype.fields['month'][1] + dataresale.dtype.fields['month'][0].itemsize // 50 * 5
month = np.ndarray(buffer=dataresale, shape=dataresale.shape, offset=moffset, strides=dataresale.strides, dtype='U2').astype(int)
```

**PPS**

It's really bothering me that there isn't a generic string slicing method in numpy. It seems pretty simple to implement given the example above. So here's a more general solution:

```
def char_slice(a, start, stop=None):
    """
    Apply `slice` to each element of string array `a`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    a : array-like
        Must contain a ascii or unicode elements.
    start, stop : int
        The limits of the slice. Only contiguous one-directional
        slices are supported. If only `start` is provided, the
        slice is interpreted as `(0, start)`, as ususal in python.
        Bounds past the ends of the string are silently truncated,
        as with most python slicing. Negative slice values are
        interpreted relative to the end of the datatype, not
        necessarily contents of the individual elements. `start` is
        inclusive, while `stop` is exclusive. `start <= stop` is
        required after all other adjustments have been made.

    Return
    ------
    slice : np.ndarray
        A view of the original data, sliced to show strings of the
        required size. The dimensions of the array will be the same
        as those of the input, and the datatype will be `SN` or
        `UN`, with the same byte order and code as the input, but
        with `N = stop - start`.

    Note
    ----
    There are two circumstances under which a view can not be
    returned. The simplest is when the data is not in a suitable
    format, such as a list or other array-like. As a rule of thumb,
    anything that `numpy.asanarray` would copy becomes a copy. The
    second circumstance is when the original base of the array `a`
    is non-contiguous. `a` itself does not have to be contiguous for
    a view to be successfully constructed.
    """
    a = np.asanyarray(a)
    dtype = a.dtype

    if dtype.char not in 'US':
        raise TypeError(f'Only U and S string datatypes supported. Found {dtype.char}')

    length = int(dtype.str[2:])

    # Adjust the bounds using a slice object
    if stop is None:
        start, stop = 0, start
    start, stop, step = slice(start, stop).indices(length)
    if start > stop or step != 1:
        raise ValueError('Invalid start-stop combination. Start <= stop required after adjustment.')

    # Get the real dtype information
    charsize = dtype.itemsize // length

    # Find the real base array
    base = a
    while base.base is not None:
        base = base.base
    realoffset = a.__array_interface__['data'][0] - base.__array_interface__['data'][0]

    newoffset = start * charsize + realoffset
    newdtype = np.dtype(f'{dtype.str[:2]}{stop - start}')
    try:
        newarray = np.ndarray(buffer=base, offset=newoffset, shape=a.shape, strides=a.strides, dtype=newdtype)
    except ValueError as e:
        if str(e) == 'ndarray is not contiguous':
            a = a.copy()
            newarray = np.ndarray(buffer=a, offset=start * charsize, shape=a.shape, strides=a.strides, dtype=newdtype)
        else:
            raise
    return newarray
```

Now all you need to do to get the year out is

```
year = char_slice(strs = dayaresale['month'], 4).astype(int)
```

Comment: For this to work you are going to need `dayaresale['month'].copy()` because it won't like the resizing of a non c-contiguous array, but upvoted because that's a pretty heroic effort!

Comment: Thanks :). They're all very cheap operations except the copy.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. Thanks for the catch I had the copy after for some tests. This actually makes it more legible.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. I added the seamless non-copying call to `np.ndarray`. It's actually not too bad if strides don't bother you.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. I've completely eliminated the need for copying with the newly added function. It straight up finds the contiguous base array so the low-level constructor has nothing to complain about.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with the help of [pandas.Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) as follows:

```
dataresale[pd.Series(dataresale['month']).str.match(r'^2021-')]
```

Comment: if you are going to use `pandas`, you might as well take advantage of the extensive datetime capabilities in the library

Answer (score 0):

Starting with numpy version 1.23.0, you can create views of non-contiguous arrays ([PR #20722](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/20722))<sup>1</sup>. The change was motivated by this question, among others, so I'm posting a second answer. Now you can do

```
dataresale['month'][:, None].view('U1')[:, :4].view('U4').squeeze().astype(int)
```

This is still annoying, so I added another layer, `np.char.slice_`, based on [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70547269/2988730) here. [PR #20694](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/20694)<sup>1</sup> is still currently a WIP, pending a change to `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` that is unrelated to this question. If/when that goes through, you will be able to do this instead:

```
np.char.slice_(dataresale['month'], 4).astype(int)
```

The code in the PR is completely functional, but has some hacky workarounds, so I do not recommend using it just yet.

<sub><sup>1</sup>I am the author. This is a shameless plug, not spam.</sub>